# Volume absorbtion: Material doesnt fully covered the mesh

Tags: materials, volumetrics

Based on this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdWUjEMzDhg&list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U&t=431s

I tried to change the liquid in a cup into coffee by adding Volume Absorbtion. But the liquid changed only on the upper surface and water can be seen through the cup instead of coffee.

[image]

In Edit Mode, selecting the entire object (liquid) and applying material to it did not work. Can anyone help me with this?

Blender file - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PcReS-QLzC6xujZujRuFIlUbcvQMmm_K/view?usp=sharing

Finding a mistake is very important to me because I started to learn and I prefer to understand where I made the mistake :)

Thanks!